# mysql - select where words matching

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any way to do SELECT query and bring only matching words between what user search and some columns in the DB ?

For instant, this is my table:
DB table - id, title, keywords

```
1 ; first title here        ; ticket flight 
2 ; second title            ; ticket airport cheap agency
3 ; third title goes here   ; vacation website flight buy online cheap
4 ; fourth title            ; car license insurance
```

user search for string "Best online website to buy cheap flight tickets"

I would like to find only the results that KEYWORDS column contain the words form the user string search, and sort it by the rows/records that contain the most matching words to the less.

I know that in PHP i can do use "array_intersect"

```
$differenceCount = count(array_intersect($array_1, $array_2));
```

is there anything similar in SQL query?

Comment: yes a full text index with match and search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nbk said in comment, I never used it so i tested it ;)

[Full-Text Index search](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
SELECT search.*,
MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('flight ticket' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AS keyword_match
FROM search 
ORDER BY keyword_match DESC;
---

**Query #1**

    SELECT search.*,
    MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('flight ticket' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AS keyword_match
    FROM search 
    ORDER BY keyword_match DESC;

| product_id | title  | keywords                                 | keyword_match        |
| ---------- | ------ | ---------------------------------------- | -------------------- |
| 3          | title3 | ticket flight                            | 0.12162718921899796  |
| 5          | title5 | ticket flight airport cheap              | 0.12162718921899796  |
| 2          | title2 | ticket airport cheap agency              | 0.0906190574169159   |
| 1          | title1 | vacation website flight buy online cheap | 0.031008131802082062 |
| 6          | title6 | flight airport cheap                     | 0.031008131802082062 |
| 4          | title4 | car license insurance                    | 0                    |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9F2oeD9rwRP2FYsncFSBRY/2)